# clang 3.9, auto_ptr and boost

Tags: c++, boost, clang

I encountered errors when trying to compile boost with clang 3.9 in c++1z mode since auto_ptr is removed in c++17. However, I successfully compiled boost with c++14 mode and linked the lib files to the executables compiled with c++1z mode. So, is there going to be any ABI issues or potential bugs in the future ?

Comment: @Ðаn, of course, but it is the boost library that uses auto_ptr so I need to switch to the c++14 mode to pass the compilation, then link against c++1z executables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There shouldn't be any ABI issues with `auto_ptr`, since it's a header-only feature - nothing in the libc++.dylib.

You can also get `auto_ptr` back in libc++ by defining `_LIBCPP_ENABLE_CXX17_REMOVED_AUTO_PTR` before including any libc++ headers.

The best solution is to ask the maintainer of whatever boost library you're using to not use `auto_ptr` when you're compiling for C++17.

Comment: But it is not only the ABI problem with auto_ptr, instead, it is combining 2 target files with different compiler flags. However, applying the macro in c++1z mode should do the work without ABI concerns. And, thanks for sharing the knowledge.

Comment: Combining 2 target files with different compiler flags is fraught with problems.  Sometimes, they just won't link (`-arch i386` and `-arch x86_64`, say).  Sometimes, they'll work just fine (example above). Sometimes, they'll appear to work until you make one particular call (`-d _LIBCPP_ABI_ALTERNATE_STRING_LAYOUT`).